# K&R C-Book: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2

Tags: c

i'm completing the exercises in the K&R book, 1-16 requires you to modify a program that prints the longest input line.

From what I understand the authors have written their own version of a library function `getline()` and perhaps that's where the error is coming from - maybe not.

I'm getting a few errors when running the below - any ideas?

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 //maximum input line size

int getline(char line[], int maxline);

// program to print all input lines > 80 characters
int main(void) {
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0 ) {
        printf("%d", len);
    }
}

// getline: read a line into s, return length
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c !='\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

**Errors**
I'm guessing the second error is since getline is already defined right?

```
1-17.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char line[], int maxline);


/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:355:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);


/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:355:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);


1-17.c:17:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
```

Comment: `getline` is not part of standard C, and won't be described in K&R, but it is a POSIX function. So the compiler expects you to use the POSIX function. To write your own `getline`, you need to use a different name.

Comment: @Inian He didn't; the author of the book did, probably long before `getline` was added to the POSIX lib with POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: thanks for the response guys, func is named that way in the book.. changing it does fix it

Comment: .... or do not compile as POSIX.  Research your compiler options.